# Doxygen can't seem to see my .d files

Tags: doxygen, d

I'm trying to use Doxygen to generate documentation for a project I'm doing in D. However, it only seems to pick up my README.md file and none of my source files, even though they're in the same directory. What should I do to make Doxygen notice my D files?

Comment: Did you try to add the *.d files explicitly to FILE_PATTERNS?